# Python: swapping negative numbers on a given list to a string

Tags: python, string, list, negative-number

Given a list of numbers swap any negative num with the string "neg"
[1,2-3,4-5,6 ] => [1,2,"-neg",4,"-neg",6]

```
def swapToNeg(lis):
    for i in lis:
        if (i < 0):
            lis[i] = "neg"
    print(lis)
```

I keep running into 2 types of errors that I cant seem to figure out.
--> 1 - IndexError: list assignment index out of range
--> 2 - TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

How can you change the number to a string
by accessing the index manually but cant change a number to string when you iterate through it compare and change??? this is eating me up...

Comment: `for i in lis` iterates over the _itens_ in the list, not their indices.

Comment: Your initial list has 4 items: 1, (2-3), (4-5), and 6. Your desired result has 6 items. As the math operations are evaluated (2-3)=-1 by python, we wil not be able to tell if the term contained a negative subtrahend. So your desired result could at maximum be [1, "-neg","-neg",6]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use `i` as both the list index and the value at that index in the list. For the for loop you've constructed just iterates over values, not incremental indices.

You probably want something like this where you iterate over index values. You can use the `range` operator to enumerate from `0..len(lis)-1`

```
def swapToNeg(lis):
    list_length = len(lis)   
    for i in range(list_length):
        if (lis[i] < 0):
            lis[i] = "neg"
    print(lis)
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response on such a basic question lol. I knew! that the len() method had to be called in a way to try to compare the actual value.

Comment: Or you could rebuild the list: `lis = [i if i >= 0 else '-neg' for i in lis]`

Answer (score 1):

What you have now is iterating over the items in the list. `i` is being set equal to `1`, `2-3`, `4-5` etc. You are receiving the `TypeError` because when `i = 2-3`, you change the `6` to the string `"neg"`. then, when `i = 4-5`, the last element of the list is accessed again, but now `i[-1] = "neg"`. since "neg" is a string, it cannot be compared to an integer.
there are a couple of ways to update your function:

1. you can use `range` so that `i` represents the index of each element. `i` will start as `0` and increase by `1` up until the length of the list. in the for loop, you would need to access `lis[i]` instead of just `i`.

```
def swapToNeg(lis):
    for i in range(len(lis)):
        if (lis[i] < 0):
            lis[i] = "neg"
    print(lis)
```

2. you can combine looping over elements and using indices using `enumerate`. see some documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). in the example below `el` will store the item looped over (1,2-3,4-5...) and `i` will store the index of the item looped over (0,1,2...).

```
def swapToNeg(lis):
    for el, i in enumerate(lis):
        if (el < 0):
            lis[i] = "neg"
    print(lis)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not accessing list properly
this code works

```
lis=[1,-2,3]
for i in lis:
  if i<0:
    lis[lis.index(i)]='neg'
```

Comment: How does that code work if the list has other negative values in it that aren't -2.

Comment: This only works, when you know that your only negative number is -2.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).